# Access elements created dynamically by extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, selenium

I'm using Firefox 41.0 along with Selenium 2.47.3 webdriver.
Our application is developed in ExtJS and we are getting some dynamic buttons upon clicking certain elements.

My webdriver is unable to access this element. So, I'm trying to execute a javascript module within python webdriver call.

I'm unable to access the element which dynamically gets loaded on web page.

How to access these kind of elements. The button click is supposed to bring a popup defined in the dynamic content.

Dynamic elements generated by ExtJS thorough an ajax call:

[image]

Failing while trying to execute click on this element from javascript:

[image]

Comment: Not really clear on what you're asking, what makes it different from any other element?

Comment: The click is not working. When I click the element manually it opens a popup. The same is not working when I execute in javascript. Because this element is generated dynamically, I suspect the click is not working. How can I access this element and execute 'click' on it.

Comment: Are you sure the element is created by the time you're trying to access it?

Comment: Yes, I can see it on webpage. I tried to execute the script in console as I shared in the above screenshot. The same is working with latest versions of Fierfox. Unfortunately due to version compatibility with Selenium webdriver, I'm can't move to latest version of firefox. Is there any way to tell my javascript to find the dynamic elements after the page load.

Comment: I'd imagine selenium would have something built in to handle that. Anyway, this doesn't seem like an Ext problem so I can't really add much more here.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element before clicking it? You should get an error if it tries to click the element and it's not there. What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. When I try to access the element with id, its showing. But the click method is not working on it. My biggest worry is to bind the click method which is already defined for it.

Comment: One more interesting this is, when I execute a $(":button") in console, its not showing this newly created buttons after ajax call. Its shows the element with id though. I might be missing something with the new elements here.

Comment: So you can *manually* click it and it works, but using jQuery's `click()` method does not work?

Comment: yes, the manual click works. I just observed there is one more element with the same id(I didn't develop this application) which exists when the page loads first. The $('extgen102') is getting hold of the first duplicate element with this id. Still figuring how to get hold of this dynamic element.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get component with Ext.

Example:

```
Ext.getCmp('id').fireEvent('click');
```